# Oak veneer finishing

Tags: finish-selection, veneer

I just brought an oak veneer to decorate my apartment. (picture 1)
However the colour is too white and I want to make it a little bit yellow as in the next picture.

What would be the right wood finish for this? Should I use oil, wax or oil-based polyurethane?

Thanks!!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Typically that yellow hue is associated with an oil finish, such as boiled linseed oil or tung oil.  However, since the material you have already seems to have a film finish on it you will not be able to apply an oil finish.

I would recommend trying an oil-based polyurethane or an amber shellac.  They should both impart some color.  The shellac will be more likely to bond well with the previous finish, but is more difficult to work with than a polyurethane.

The most important thing with any kind of color matching like this is to first try it on a test piece.  It is very hard to recommend a specific product over the internet as colors vary wildly with different lighting, cameras, monitors, etc.  A test piece will also let you make sure the new finish will bond to the previous finish.